# Java Tapestry Autocomplete typeahead include ID on listing

Tags: java, autocomplete, tapestry, typeahead

I have a textfield which uses autocomplete mixin on tapestry. The mixin is working fine as it is, but I am having a problem with tagging the values of list of names with duplicate values. Now I am wondering if I can somehow pass the id of the data on autocomplete upon selection.

Here is my code for pupulating the list.

```
List<String> onProvideCompletionsFromUserName(String partial) {
        List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
        String partialUpper = partial.toUpperCase();

    List<User> users = clientFinder.findUsers();
    // int i = 0;

    for (User user : users){
        String name = NameUtil.toName(user.getFirstName(), user.getFamilyName());

        if (name.toUpperCase().contains(partialUpper)) {
            matches.add(name );
            // if (i++ >= 5) {
            // break;
            // }
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Is there a way for me to pass the ID with the list like

**(List onProvideCompletionsFromUserName)**?

Has anyone encountered this problem as well ? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to do it was by extending the `Autocomplete` mixin with my own version, as the `configure` method in the mixin is marked protected. Here is my class. Note that I am firing my own event. You will have to give your own values for `label`, `value` and `uid` in the `providecompletions` handler. The zone parameter is the zone you want to update when the user clicks and item in the completion list.

**Mixin:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.tapestry5.BindingConstants;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ComponentResources;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.OnEvent;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject;
import org.apache.tapestry5.json.JSONLiteral;
import org.apache.tapestry5.json.JSONObject;
import org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.mixins.Autocomplete;

public class UserAutocomplete extends Autocomplete {
    public static final String CHANGE_EVENT_NAME = "autocompleteUser";

    @Inject
    private ComponentResources resources;

    @Parameter(defaultPrefix=BindingConstants.LITERAL)
    private String zone;

    @OnEvent(value = "provideCompletions")
    public List<JSONObject> autoComplete(String query) {
        List<JSONObject> strings = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

        if(query != null) {
            for(User u : service.searchUsers(query.trim())) {
                JSONObject so = new JSONObject();
                String name = u.getName();
                so.put("label", name);
                so.put("value", name);
                so.put("uid", u.getId());
                strings.add(so);
            }
        }

        return strings;
    }


    protected void configure(JSONObject config) {
        config.put("url", resources.createEventLink("autocomplete").toURI());
        String url = resources.createEventLink(CHANGE_EVENT_NAME).toURI();
        config.put("options", new JSONObject().put("select", new JSONLiteral("function(e, d) {var zone = $('#" + zone + "'); if (!zone) { return; } "
                + "zone.tapestryZone('update', {url: '" + url + "'+'/'+d.item.uid});}")));
    }
}
```

**Page Template:**

```
<t:textfield value="query" autocomplete="off" t:mixins="UserAutocomplete" t:zone="resultZone" />
```

**Page Class:**

```
...

@InjectComponent
private Zone resultZone;

@OnEvent(value = UserAutocomplete.CHANGE_EVENT_NAME)
void userChange(Integer id) {
    User selectedUser = service.findUser(id);
    renderer.addRender(resultZone);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.